# Search and update a JSON array element in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have a Jsonb column that store array of elements like the following:

```
[ 
  {"id": "11", "name": "John", "age":"25", ..........}, 
  {"id": "22", "name": "Mike", "age":"35", ..........},
  {"id": "33", "name": "Tom",  "age":"45", ..........},
  .....
]
```

I want to replace the 2nd object(id=22) with a totally new object.  I don't want to update each property one by one because there are many properties and their values all could have changed. I want to just identify the 2nd element and replace the whole object.

I know there is a jsonb_set(). However, to update the 2nd element, I need to know its array index=1 so I can do the following:

```
jsonb_set(data, '{1}', '{"id": "22", "name": "Don", "age":"55"}',true)
```

But I couldn't find any way to search and get that index. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Q: Have you tried the JSON operators: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way I can think of is to combine `row_number` and `json_array_elements`:

```
-- test data
create table test (id integer, data jsonb);
insert into test values (1, '[{"id": "22", "name": "Don", "age":"55"}, {"id": "23", "name": "Don2", "age":"55"},{"id": "24", "name": "Don3", "age":"55"}]');
insert into test values (2, '[{"id": "32", "name": "Don", "age":"55"}, {"id": "33", "name": "Don2", "age":"55"},{"id": "34", "name": "Don3", "age":"55"}]');

select subrow, id, row_number() over (partition by id) 
from (
    select json_array_elements(data) as subrow, id 
    from test
) as t;
                  subrow                  | id | row_number
------------------------------------------+----+------------
 {"id": "22", "name": "Don", "age":"55"}  |  1 |          1
 {"id": "23", "name": "Don2", "age":"55"} |  1 |          2
 {"id": "24", "name": "Don3", "age":"55"} |  1 |          3
 {"id": "32", "name": "Don", "age":"55"}  |  2 |          1
 {"id": "33", "name": "Don2", "age":"55"} |  2 |          2
 {"id": "34", "name": "Don3", "age":"55"} |  2 |          3

-- apparently you can filter what you want from here
select subrow, id, row_number() over (partition by id) 
from (
    select json_array_elements(data) as subrow, id 
    from test
) as t
where subrow->>'id' = '23';
```

In addition, think about your schema design. It may not be the best idea to store your data this way.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response @blurrcat.  I am trying to accomplish the update with one single query.  With your solution, how do I pass the row_number to the jsonb_set()?

Comment: I literally answered your question of "get that index".. It would be awkward to do it in one query, if possible. Also, consider cases where there are multiple subrows matching that id. If you have the liberty to change the schema I think it's best to put those subrows in a separate table.

Comment: Ok, @blurrcat. Thank you.  Can you also elaborate your suggestion of schema design? What would be a better way?

Comment: @user3487866 how about putting the array items in a separate table?